# Is it possible to turn off anti-aliasing depending on the performance of the device?

Tags: three.js

For reasons unknown to me *all* 3D websites have horrible performance on my fairly decent Dell XPS laptop(very low FPS, 3 at worst, 12 at best). And I mean, even GitHub's main page globe lags on it.

After some testing, I discovered that turning off anti-aliasing on my three.js website fixes the issue completely. I am aware there are various types of AA, but I've found all of them to lag (including FXAA that's often recommended in similar cases)

Now, I understand that's mostly my laptop's issue, but I come from a place that this is your average real world scenario; after all, who doesn't have that one friend who keeps using their 10 year old junk laptop?

So I was just wondering, can I turn off AA for slow laptops and keep it on for performant machines? My preferred way of adding AA is with `const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});`

Comment: Unfortunately, there’s no way to preemptively detect if the device will perform well with antialias enabled. See here for a related conversation I had on this topic a few years ago: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/changing-renderer-antialias-on-the-fly/16259/9